# Stacking my conditions in a CASE statement it's not returning all cases for each member

Tags: sql, case, teradata

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    Member_ID,
    CASE 
        WHEN a.ASTHMA_MBR = 1 THEN 'ASTHMA'  
        WHEN a.COPD_MBR = 1 THEN 'COPD' 
        WHEN a.HYPERTENSION_MBR = 1 THEN 'HYPERTENSION' 
    END AS DX_FLAG
```

So a member may have more than one, but my statement is only returning one of them.

I'm using Teradata and trying to convert multiple columns of boolean data into one column. The statement is only returning one condition when members may have 2 or more. I tried using `Select` instead of `Select Distinct` and it made no difference.

Comment: What do you expect when a member has multiple conditions?  Multiple rows? A single row with some kind of combined value in the `DX_FLAG` column?  Something else?

Comment: Do you have an example to how you want the results to appear? Your results will always show one per ID here. There is only 1 ID per member, therefor your case statement will trigger the first WHEN clause that returns true. CASE statements are for returning a specific set back, not multiple sets

Comment: I want multiple rows @JohnBollinger

Comment: 00001044801 Hypertension 3/1/2022 12/31/9999
00001050801 Hypertension 5/1/2019 10/31/2022
00001058601 Asthma         4/1/2020 12/31/9999
00001067101 Hypertension 8/1/2022 12/31/9999
00001071601 COPD         9/1/2021 12/31/9999
00001071601 Hypertension 9/1/2021 12/31/9999
00001078201 Hypertension 2/1/2022 12/31/9999
00001079001 Asthma         6/17/2021 12/31/9999
00001079001 Hypertension 6/17/2021 12/31/9999

Comment: What do you want for a user with none of these diagnoses? Included in the result or not?

Comment: @jarlh not included in the results

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of UNPIVOT:

```
with base_data as
 ( -- select the columns you want to unpivot
   select
      member_id
     ,date_col

      -- the aliases will be the final column value
     ,ASTHMA_MBR AS ASTHMA
     ,COPD_MBR AS COPD
     ,HYPERTENSION_MBR AS HYPERTENSION
   from your_table
 )
,unpvt as
 (
   select member_id, date_col, x, DX_FLAG
   from base_data
   -- now unpivot those columns into rows
   UNPIVOT(x FOR DX_FLAG IN (ASTHMA, COPD, HYPERTENSION)
          ) dt
 )
select member_id, DX_FLAG, date_col
from unpvt
-- only show rows where the condition is true
where x = 1
```